# ActiveRecords: Search only on non empty parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

So I have to search on three fields. Age AND Sex AND Ethnicity

if only Age is given I have to return all records matching the age. If Age and Ethnicity are given but sex is empty then only return matching records for age and ethnicity. etc..

The naive way of solving this is like this:

```
class Profile

  def self.search_profile(search_params_array)
    if search_params_array.first != nil && search_params_array.second != null && search_params_array.third != null
      Profile.where("age = ?", search_params_array.first).where("sex = ?", search_params_array.second).where("ethnicity = ?", search_params_array.third)
    end
    ... 
    ... # We can permutate between all possible conditions where one of the element is nil
    ...
  end
end
```

What is a better way to approach this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class Profile

  def self.search_profile(search_params_array)
    params = %w(age sex ethnicity).zip(search_params_array).reject do |_, v|
      v.nil? 
    end.to_h
    where(params)
  end

end
```

If you can pass the search params as a hash, things can get much easier.

Comment: to_h doesn't seem to work for my version of ruby. Will fix it and check for the correctness of your solution

Comment: @user5233972 so what's your version of ruby?

Comment: @user5233972 if `Array#to_h` is not available to you, use `Hash::[](ary)` instead

Comment: Version is 2.0.0p481.

Comment: @user5233972 try removing `.to_h`, and insert a line `params = Hash[params]` before `where(params)`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a if else block or a switch case statement based on your logic.

Comment: that's true.. But I am hoping for a sql query/activerecord based solution.. This situation described in the question is pretty common.

Answer (score 0):

You can chain the conditions depending on the presence of the params.

```
class Profile
  def self.searchprofile(search_params_array)
    scope = Profile.all
    %w(age sex ethnicity).zip(search_params_array).each do |k, v|
      next if v.blank?
      scope = scope.where(k => v)
    end
  end
end
```

PS: I borrowed the `zip` trick from Aetherus' answer!